# GLIBC_2.29' not found

Tags: python-3.x, glibc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHkJR.jpg)

ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

Hei

I am on a Rasberry pi 4B / 8 GB, Raspberry OS / Buster, using debian 10.

i'm currently using python 3.10.4 as a standard version

i have installed
pip install grpcio==1.44.0 --no-binary=grpcio
pip install grpcio-tools==1.44.0 --no-binary=grpcio-tools
but it didn't do anything at all

anyone who can help?

Comment: How do you install python 3.10.4 or python 3.11É

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry OS is using musllibc, while most other Linux distros are using glibc. This means the binary wheels gRPC team uploaded to PyPI won't work out-of-box for Raspberry Pi. I would recommend to download the wheels from piwheels: https://www.piwheels.org/project/grpcio/